# UWP WebAuthenticationBroker and SSO

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, uwp

I'm trying to perform OAuth code grant authentication using the WebAuthenticationBroker.  Everything works fine up to the point of authentication and obtaining the access token.  What I also require is the ability for multiple apps to perform single sign on.  So the expected behavior is

1. The user starts app A and attempts authentication
2. WAB navigates to the authorization URL and the end user enters credentials
3. WAB returns the authorization code as result, which is used to obtain the access token

Now, without logging out of app A, suppose the user starts and attempts authentication in app B, my understanding of SSO leads me to believe the end user should not be prompted for credentials by WAB when making the authorization code request from app B.  However, WAB does prompt for credentials, thereby not allowing for an SSO experience.

Few additional points:

1. The custom OAuth server I'm using complies to WAB requirements (All SSL endpoints with trusted certificate and allows registration of callback URIs of ms-appx:// format.
2. I am using the AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions options, Uri requestUri) overload of WAB
3. Both app A and app B are authenticating to the same provider
4. The callback URIs for the individual apps are registered (Evident from the fact that the apps can perform authentication by themselves)

Based on the following links, my understanding is that SSO should work across app A and app B as long as WAB requirements are met and redirect URIs conform to the ms-appx format:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-authentication-broker

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br212068.aspx

Excerpt from above link:

"When this method is used, session state or persisted cookies are retained across multiple calls from the same or different Windows Store apps."

I've tried using different values for WebAuthenticationOptions in the first param of AuthenticateAsync (WebAuthenticationOptions.None/UseHttpPost in app A and WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode in app B and few other combinations), but I simply cannot get SSO to work between app A and app B.

The questions are:

1. Is my understanding of how WAB supports SSO accurate, or have I simply misunderstood the documentation?
2. Are there any other requirements to getting WAB SSO to work?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Not posting any code samples since this involves simple calls to WebAuthenticationBroker.

PPS: Did not find much info about WAB & SSO hence posting a new question.

Comment: Does your app a support single sign on? For example, if you want to login to FB from any other app on your windows phone, if you are signed into FB App it doesn't give you login screen. This is single signon. So in this case your App A should also support single sign on for app B.

Comment: @AVK Naidu: That is precisely what I'm trying to achieve with WebAuthenticationBroker.  From what I understand from MSDN regarding cookie persistence used by WAB, it should support SSO between apps without having to authenticate in any specific order between the apps.